# How to reduce the spacing for empty dates in title (when using the titling package)

Tags: spacing, titles, etoolbox, titling

I am looking for a marco which changes the behaviour of `date` (while using the `titling` package) in the case the date is empty.

This  MWE **A** should give a document as normal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{A date test title}
\date{13 Dec 13}

%
% Here go the tweak macros enhancing the behaviour of \date
% ...
% ...
%

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

But for the following MWE **B** I want a result with  a smaller space between title and text because there is no date printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{A date test title}
\date{} % DATE IS NOW EMPTY!

%
% Here go the tweak macros enhancing the behaviour of \date
% ...
% ...
%

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this with **generic** tweak macros (changing probably the internal commands of the `titling` package) so that the same tweak works in both cases, for empty dates and set dates.

The tweak macros somehow have to test whether `\@date` is empty or not. I tried `\ifdefempty` (from the `etoolbox` package) but \@date seems to be never empty, even if no date gets printed (i.e. `\date{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The titling package (`titling.sty`) renews the command `\maketitle`. The printing of the date happens in `\maketitle` or, if no own page is created (for example article class) in `\@maketitle` which is invoked by `\maketitle`. So be sure you know which macro you need to patch. Then you can simply exchange its content with `\pathcmd` from `etoolbox` package. (Of course you could write a solution for both cases using `\if@titlepage` but I think for normal purposes that's not necessary.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling,etoolbox}
\title{A date test title}
\date{13 Dec 13}
% \date{}

\makeatletter
\ifx\@date\empty
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{{\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate} \maketitlehookd \par \vskip 1.5em}{\vskip 0.5em}{}{}
% \patchcmd{\maketitle}{{\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate} \maketitlehookd \par}{\vskip 0.5em}{}{}%for document classes with extra title pages
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the date. I didn't know about `\patchcmd`. Thanks.

Comment: However it does not work for the author *if you don't set `\author{}`*, but just leave it as is. The test has to be different then: `\sbox0{\@author}\ifdim\wd0=\z@` (instead of `\ifx\@author\empty`).

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{A date test title}
\author{Author}
\makeatletter
\predate{%
  \ifx\@empty\thedate\relax
  \else\begin{center}\large
  \fi}
\postdate{%
  \ifx\@empty\thedate\relax
  \else\par\end{center}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\date{} % DATE IS NOW EMPTY!
\maketitle
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image: comparison with and without date]